# Convert binary data to jpeg

Tags: matlab, binary, jpeg

I have spent the last couple hours scouring the Internet for a solution to my problem, and while I have seen some "answers" on other forums, none of them suit my needs...

I have a binary file, which I am creating in Matlab using fwrite (although, if someone has a better way to generate a binary file in Matlab, I'm open to suggestions). Back to my problem - I have this binary file, and I want to convert it to a jpeg. Nevermind where the binary data comes from, I just want to generate a jpeg image of the binary data.

Is this even possible? - Like I said, lots of "solutions" out there to similar problems, but none match up to my needs.

I can write code in C++, if necessary, but for simplicity, I'd like to stay in Matlab.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html . What kind of binary file? Convert it into a matlab image (rgb matrix).

Comment: This is asking for an array, A. I am reading the binary file into an array (which I'm calling "B") using fscanf, but when I use imwrite, I get an error telling me the array should not be a string.

Comment: This needs more description of what is contained in the "binary" files.  NxMx3 uint8's?   NxM single precision values?  Some camera's *.raw format?  This also needs some sample code.  For example, nothing in the original post would lead me to think that you had managed to read a string.  Once you can read the data correctly, creating a JPEG is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

[from binary to array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html):

```
fid = fopen('yourfilename.bin');

% read the entire file as characters
% transpose so that F is a row vector
B = fread(fid, '*char')'

fclose(fid);
```

Reshape to array according to image dimensions

```
C=reshape(B,512,512); % or whatever dimension you have
```

Upon having the array of strings just use:

```
D=int32(str2num(C));
```

Comment: I'm running into issues with converting the binary file to an array. If I open the .bin file using a text editor, it is unreadable (as it should be - being a binary file). How can I get the binary file into an array? Or is there another way to solve this problem?